# Limit characters retrieved on a certain column from Select query

Tags: sql, oracle

Inquiring if there is a way to limit the characters of a certain column in a select statement.

ex. SELECT ADDRESS FROM EMPLOYEETABLE;

ADDRESS is of type VARCHAR2(500) but I want to limit the number of characters that it will output to 100.

Answer (score 1):

Use `SUBSTR`:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(address,1,100)
  FROM employeetable;
```

Answer (score 1):

### To get data of a fixed length from a column in MSSQL or Oracle

Yes, you can do it by using SUBSTRING() function in MSSql and SUBSTR() in Oracle.

For example:
Let's say we have a table test_emp with fields name, mobile and emp_address.

MSSQL & Oracle Syntax

```
create table test_emp(name varchar(30),mobile varchar(10),emp_address varchar(500));
```

Now insert some data in test_emp table.

MSSQL & Oracle Syntax

```
insert into test_emp(name,mobile,emp_address)  values('Anonymous','0123456789','Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum');
```

The length of the given data in emp_address field is 359
To check the length
MSSQL Syntax

```
select len('Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum')
```

Oracle Syntax

```
select Length('Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum')
```

Now you can use the select statement to get the desired output

In MSSQL

```
select name,mobile,SUBSTRING(emp_address,1,100) from test_emp;
```

In Oracle

```
select name,mobile,SUBSTR(emp_address,1,100) from test_emp;
```